# Flutter: how to create a non-final property for a StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, attributes, state, final

Say I want to create a button that every time that it's clicked it changes color.
Its starting color is required in the constructor.

The following code works fine, but  when I hover on top of TestButton I get this message: "This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final: TestButton.color".

If it should be final but I need it to change, what's the solution?
Why does it have be final if it works anyways?

```
class TestButton extends StatefulWidget {
  TestButton({this.color});
  Color color;
  @override
  _TestButtonState createState() => _TestButtonState();
}

class _TestButtonState extends State<TestButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          widget.color = widget.color == Colors.red ? Colors.blue : Colors.red;
        });
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
        size: 80,
      ),
      color: widget.color,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can have variables in the `State` object of the `StatefulWidget`, not in the `StatefulWidget` itself.

If you need to pass the value from another widget, you can pass it and reassign it to a `State` variable in the `initState` function.

Example:

```dart
class TestButton extends StatefulWidget {
  TestButton({this.passedcolor});
  final Color passedColor;
  @override
  _TestButtonState createState() => _TestButtonState();
}

class _TestButtonState extends State<TestButton> {
  Color color;

  @override
  initState(){
   color = widget.passedColor;
   super.initState()
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          color = color == Colors.red ? Colors.blue : Colors.red;
        });
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
        size: 80,
      ),
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

and then you can update it using `setState` to any color you wish.

As to why the value passed in the constructor has to be `final` or why you can't change it is because the `StatefulWidget` itself is immutable and holds immutable data, but it also holds a mutable `State` object which is a store for all the state `aka mutable data` the widget requires.

Quoting from Flutter docs:

> StatefulWidget instances themselves are immutable and store their mutable state either in separate State objects that are created by the createState method, or in objects to which that State subscribes, for example Stream or ChangeNotifier objects, to which references are stored in final fields on the StatefulWidget itself.

You can read more on it here: 
[StatefulWidget class documentation on Flutter website](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Comment: Thanks! I read the documentation, but I don't understand why does my code work just as well as yours? I tested it both on my phone and on an emulator. If If I shouldn't have variables in a StatefulWidget, why does it work anyways?

Comment: You are welcome! I have also updated my code since it had some mistakes, I am not sure but I feel like what you are accessing and changing is not the actual value passed into the constructor but an instance of it, like passing arguments to a function and changing it from inside the function, you are not changing the actual immutable value, but it is still wrong that's why you get the warning (probably).
I'll investigate further soon and let you know of my findings.

Comment: Not a good practice and I ran into bugs when using this reassigning approach. I'd recommend to use `widget.passedColor` directly so it won't cause problem if the widget variable gets updated later by the framework.